# bash: exit script loop

Tags: bash

I am using zgrep - a bash script wrapper that runs grep on compressed files.

The problem is that <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> won't stop the script.
I guess the reason is that the loop over the files, spawns sub-shells, so the terminate signal goes to the running grep process, and not to the parent script. So even trap in the parent script does not work.

to illustrate:

```
trap break SIGPIPE SIGTERM SIGQUIT SIGSTOP
for i
  gzip -cdfq "$i" | grep $pattern
done
```

I also tried `"/bin/kill -- -$$"` instead of `break`, with the same results. I guess the script does not get the interrupt.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised your C-c does not work (you might want to look into `stty`). Nevertheless there are several problems with your script.

1. The `trap` command should also stop on `SIGINT`.
2. The `break` in the trap will not get you out of the loop. You'll need something like:

```
DONE=
trap 'DONE=1' SIGINT
for i in "$@"; do
    [[ -n $DONE ]] && break
    ∶
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the `bash` info documentation:

> If Bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal
>   for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the
>   command completes.

You'll need to write a wrapper in something that gives you more control over signals if you want to change that.

Comment: Yes, but the signal will _also_ be delivered to the program, thus (usually) terminating it early, and the trap then fires smartly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting similar behavior by trap (not getting executed). My environment is `ksh88` on `HP Unix`. My trap is to catch `INT KILL` and `QUIT`. I'm calling `gzip` within a shell function. If I remove `gzip` the trap handler gets executed when I send interrupt signal to it but not when I have `gzip`.

Regarding your problem: The reason that `Cntrl-C` won't stop your loop is because you are catching it by your trap. And your trap handler is not correct command to stop your loop. Your parent script won't get stop neither as it doesn't see any signal, again because by 'trap' you are saying that you want to handle it not the shell. If you want to just exit the loop then put your loop in a separate function and set the trap in that function. Just to give you an idea, here is `a.ksh`:

---

```
function f1
{
    trap return INT QUIT KILL
    i=0

    while [[ $i -lt 100 ]]
    do
        $(( i=$i+1 ))
        sleep 2
        echo $i
        done
}

echo BEFORE calling f1

f1

echo AFTER calling f1
```

---

Testing a.ksh:

```
 $ a.ksh

BEFORE calling f1 

1

2

3
```

AFTER calling f1

---

I hit `Contrl-C` after the third iteration. As you see I got `AFTER calling f1` message which means `contrl-C` just stopped the function not the entire process (`a.ksh`). Hope that helped.